# How to parse common subcommand arguments with Clap in Rust?

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I trying to build cli which should take `<command_name>` as first argument, `<path_to_file>` as last argument and options in between, so call in console would look like this:

```bash
programm command_one --option True file.txt
```

I have setup like this:

```rust
// ./src/main.rs
use clap::{Args, Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Cli {
   #[command(subcommand)]
   command: Commands,
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
struct CommandOneArgs {
   file: String,
   #[arg(short, long)]
   option_for_one: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
struct CommandTwoArgs {
   file: String,
   #[arg(short, long)]
   option_for_two: Option<String>,
}


#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
enum Commands {
   CmdOne(CommandOneArgs)
   CmdTwo(CommandTwoArgs)
}


fn main() {
   let args = Cli::parse();
   match &args.command {
      Commands::CmdOne(cmd_args) => {println!({:?}, cmd_args)}
      Commands::CmdTwo(cmd_args) => {println!({:?}, cmd_args)}
      _ => {}
   }
```

But here is the problem which i am failing to solve:
In reality in branches of match i will call some functions with obtained args;
However i need to do preparation common for all commands, e.g. read file from path
So before matching expression i need to extract `file` attribute:

```rust
fn main() {
   let args = Cli::parse();
   /// something like that
   // let file_path = args.command.file;
   // println!("reading from: {}", file_path)
   match &args.command {
      Commands::CmdOne(cmd_args) => {println!({:?}, cmd_args)}
      Commands::CmdTwo(cmd_args) => {println!({:?}, cmd_args)}
      _ => {}
   }
```

I can not do that in a way like commented.

And I can not add position argument to `Cli` struct because then interface would look like: `programm <POSITIONAL ARG> command_one ...`
I have assumptions that I should use generics, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just beginning with clap as well. While it does not entirely match your issue, I've just came across this [Github discussion](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/discussions/2559).

It would fit your needs if all your subcommands need this parameter (that's my case). The code examples are from my project, but the idea is to use the [`global` method of the Arg struct](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.Arg.html#method.global), which allows an argument to be matched to all child `Subcommand`s:

```rust
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    command: Commands,

    #[arg(global=true)]  // <-- here
    file: Option<String>
}
```

Even though the **global help** stays the same:

```
$ cargo run -- -h
[...]
Usage: fed [FILE] <COMMAND>
[...]
```

, the **subcommand helps** are updated:

```
$ cargo run -- insert -h
[...]
Usage: fed insert -n <N> --line <LINE> [FILE]
[...]
```

This probably has limits and it still allows the `file` argument to be given first, but there might be some way to improve this. I'll update this answer if I find something better in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Would abstracting the logic of retrieving the value of the `file` argument into methods on `Commands` and `Cli` be an option for you? Something like this:

```rust
use clap::{Args, Parser, Subcommand};

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Cli {
    #[command(subcommand)]
    command: Commands,
}

impl Cli {
    fn file(&self) -> &str {
        self.command.file()
    }
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
struct CommandOneArgs {
    file: String,
    #[arg(short, long)]
    option_for_one: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
struct CommandTwoArgs {
    file: String,
    #[arg(short, long)]
    option_for_two: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Subcommand, Debug)]
enum Commands {
    CmdOne(CommandOneArgs),
    CmdTwo(CommandTwoArgs),
}

impl Commands {
    fn file(&self) -> &str {
        match self {
            Self::CmdOne(args) => &args.file,
            Self::CmdTwo(args) => &args.file,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args = Cli::parse();

    let file_path = args.file();

    println!("{file_path}");
}
```

Prints `hello` if I run `cargo run -- cmd-one hello`.

Comment: Indeed it should work, and  if no one suggest solutions without additional impls,  i will use your. I just believe that there should be easier way, than that, but i could be wrong.